# Designing a Login system - What's the right way to do it?

Tags: php, security

I'm somewhat new to web development and I need to develop a user system - so users can register, login etc.

I initially stored the user data in a Session variable upon login, but felt the need to re-architecture that because I realized I would never be able to support 'remember me' functions, and decided to use cookies.

My current system is this:

- User logs in: I verify username and password against stored values in DB
- I set username and password to their own cookies. username cookie persists so the username field can be populated when the user revisits. Password cookie expires when user leaves.
- Each time a page loads, my PHP script checks to see if the password cookie exists, which means the user is logged in.

The problem is, the third step seems somewhat insecure to me. Currently, I only check to see if the password cookie exists, but I do not compare it against the database everytime a page loads. Couldn't an unauthorized user create a password cookie and set it to some random string manually, and get through my authentication system? He would be able to impersonate any user by setting the user cookie manually as well. Should I be comparing the value of the password cookie against my database on every page load?

So, if I use `session` in conjunction with cookies, I imagine doing something like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
   authenticate_user_from_cookie();
   set_session('user');
}
else
{
    //user is already logged in
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `session_start()` it will reconnect the current request to a session (`$_SESSION`), or create a new session.  Apache saves these sessions to disk (by default in your `/tmp` folder) and reconnects you to the session automagically with a cookie named `PHPSESSID` (this can be changed in `PHP.INI`), that is stored after the first time you call `session_start()` on the first request.

You can authenticate your user by whatever means you want, but typically you could use lookup the username + (encrypted password - e.g. `sha1($password.'salt string that only you know')`) pair in your database or permanent storage and then simply set `$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true` or `$_SESSION['user'] = 1` or whatever flag you want in the `$_SESSION`.

You can go as far as creating a `User` class (many frameworks do that), representing everything you know about the logged-in authenticated user and then ask the object `$_SESSION['User']->isAuthenticated()` or something like that.

If you want to not have the user reenter their password each time you can implement a `Remember Me` feature (special random cookie that you generated when they authenticated and stored in the database), that will set a special cookie in their browser that won't expire at the end of the session that you look when someone makes a request who isn't authenticated.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. So, if I use `session` in conjunction with cookies, I won't need to hit the database each page load. See my pseudo code in my question: is that something more like it?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but if you can't authenticate them from the cookie you would then redirect them to your login form.  This would allow them to bookmark an **internal** page.  You could also save the internal page in the `$_SESSION`, redirect them to your login form, then after they authenticate forward them back to the page they originally requested - this is good for the User Experience.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely incorporate that as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not php specific but if you're new, I would recommend reading the [OWASP guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet).  OWASP is an excellent resource for secure web development info.  The OWASP site will cover much more than we can here.

For a more php specific answer, they have [this guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet).  Point 2.10 addresses your question more directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just checking for a cookie's existence is by no means a way to authenticate a user or validate his identity. So yes, you should be checking on every page load, if you're sticking with the cookie based authentication.  As long as there's an index / primary key on the lookup into the user table, the query will be fast to pull the user's information and check against the cookie values.

To be more specific, the cookie(s) that you're setting are *just as valuable* as the user's username and password, they're nearly synonymous. So, you can also save information about the user when you issue the cookie, such as IP and User-Agent, which you can also verify to try and ensure the cookies match the user.

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful. So, I will check against the database every time, and I'll look into adding additional fields to include IP and user agent as well.

Comment: User agents can be spoofed, plus people may change browsers on the same machine or use a different machine behind the same IP address (e.g. they connect though a router).

Comment: Cookies can be spoofed too - You're adding another layer of protection that an attacker would need to set correctly for successful authentication, albeit a relatively small layer. Personally, I think if you change browsers you should be logged off, and if they use a different machine with the same IP they'll likely have a different User-Agent, again logging them off.

Comment: If a user uses a different browser, won't he get logged out anyways, even if I dont authenticate using user-agent? I always thought cookies were browser specific, and cookies set by one browser could not be accessed by another browser.

Comment: @xbonez - Correct, the point was if they spoofed the cookies in a different browser, they'd be logged in as if they were in the original browser. By adding a user-agent check, the attacker would have to spoof **both** the cookie(s) and the User-Agent string in order to be successfully logged in

Comment: But people often upgrade their browsers?  While I like the idea of using the User Agent, just thinking it changes often.  I mean Firefox 3.6 is on what version 23?

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez - True, but if they upgrade their browser, their session cookies will be destroyed when the browser exits to upgrade itself. So they won't even have the cookies needed for authentication, regardless of a mismatch in the User-Agent.

Answer (score 0):

A few more tips:

1.) Make sure you do input validation for both the password and the userid and make certain that you are validating the values on the server side as any client-side validation can easily be bypassed by malicious users. If you don't validate on the server you will be opening yourself to various types of attacks such as SQL injection and people will be able to compromise your database. Make sure you are escaping any potentially malicious strings

2.) Make sure you have login logouts, so that if people try to to put in too many wrong credentials you block their IP for a few minutes. This will discourage brute force attacks. 
Make sure that this works for both bad userids as well as bad passwords as attackers can iterate over either (e.g. they can keep the password the same and try many user ids).

3.) If you are using salts, do not store the salt in the same place as the password hashes. If someone breaks into your database you don't want them to have both the hashes and the salts because it will make the hashes easy to crack using rainbow tables.

4.) Make sure you are using SSL/TLS to encrypt traffic traffic between the server and the user, otherwise an attacker can steal the cookie by sniffing the network and login as your user. (Look up Firesheep, it was a big problem for Facebook and Gmail for a little while...)

5.) Don't do any custom encryption schemes, use only trusted cryptographic libraries and algorithms to perform hashes. (e.g. PHP's sha1 is good, doing your own little rotation on password characters is not).

6.) As recommended, you should check out OWASP, it's the best resource for securing a web application.

Comment: for point #3: the point of salt is to make the rainbow table useless even if the attacker hacked the database.